# Javascript: Make an array of integers in same index as array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of strings, and I need a new array that has integers that represent the length of each element in same index.

Example:

```
stringArr = ["cat", "x", "hello", ""];
// new array of integers that represent each length
// newArr = [3, 1, 5, 0];
```

Comment: Use the `map()` method.

Comment: Or just write a loop that pushes the lengths onto `newArr`. This is at most 3 lines of code.

Comment: [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map` through the array, calling `length` on each item

```js
stringArr = ["cat", "x", "hello", ""];

out = stringArr.map(x => x.length)

console.log(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const stringArr = ["cat", "x", "hello", ""];

console.log(stringArr.map(s => s.length));
```

Answer (score 0):

You definitely shouldn't do it this way, but it works.

First you turn your declaration into a string:

```
const stringArrString = `stringArr = ["cat", "x", "hello", ""];`
```

Now you use regex replace to create the length string and strip away unecessary characters and eval the whole thing to produce the array, `lengthArray`

```
const lengthArray = eval(
    stringArrString.replace(/\"\w*?\"/gi, (word)=>{
        word = word.replace(/\"/gi, '');
        return word.length;
    })
    .replace(/stringArr\ =\ /, "")
    .replace(/;/, '')
);
```

So yeah, don't do this, but maybe you'll learn something if you pick it apart.